# VBA Function to open word documents based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

Having some small issues with getting this Function working. It's currently capable of identifying files based on checking whether a cell value exists, but the issue is that it's not actually opening the word document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function Method2(ByVal rngl As Range, ByVal strSearch As Variant, ByVal sPath As String)

Dim directory As String

Dim fileName As String

Dim myFile As File

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject

Dim myFolder As Folder

Dim mySubFolder As Folder

Dim objWord

Dim objDoc

Dim rngRange

Dim rng1 As Range

Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)


directory = "S:\File Recipes\"

fileName = "Yaroze_Test"

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Set rng1 = Range("A:A").find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If strSearch = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Product Code!"
    Exit Function
    End If
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Product Codes Found!"
        For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders

            For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files

                If InStr(myFile, strSearch) > 0 Then

                fileName = myFile.Name

                MsgBox (myFile.Name)

                Do While fileName <> ""

                    ChDrive ("S")

                    ChDir ("S:\File Recipes\")

                    directory = mySubFolder.Path & "\" & fileName

                    MsgBox directory

                    objWord.Documents.Open fileName:=directory

                    DoEvents

                    Exit For



                Loop

                MsgBox "Task Complete!"

                objWord.Visible = True

                End If

            Next

        Next
       ' Set rngRange = _
         objWord.Range(objWord.Paragraphs(1).Start, objWord.Paragraphs(1).End - 1)
       ' rngRange.InsertAfter _
         "This is now the last sentence in paragraph one."
        Else
            MsgBox "Product Codes Not Found!"
        End If

End Function
```

I think the issue is with:

```
objWord.Documents.Open fileName:=directory
```

But I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i tested this i found that it was causing excel to wait forever for Word to complete the ole action. After i moved the `objWord.Visible = True` before `objWord.Documents.Open Filename:=directory` I discovered Word was giving me a prompt when trying to open the file.

If you move `objWord.Visible = True` before `objWord.Documents.Open Filename:=directory` too it might be the same for you.